# localhost работает только, когда подключен к интернету

Tags: android, nginx

Всем привет! Тут на днях собрал **nginx** на **Android**. Начал тестировать. Заметил такую вещь, что когда я отключаю на телефоне **Wifi**, то сайт на **localhost** перестает работать. С чем это может быть вызвано? Спасибо заранее!

Comment: вероятно, либо браузер не может преобразовать имя (`localhost`) в ip-адрес (скорее всего — `127.0.0.1`), либо не может обратиться по этому ip-адресу, либо nginx перестаёт слушать этот адрес (например, останавливается его работа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

я думаю, что браузер перед отправкой запроса проверяет, есть ли подключение к Интернету, и если нету - то типа как *смысла отправлять запрос вообще нет, все равно не дойдет, зачем пытаться вообще?*. Попробуйте другой браузер, например

Comment: Спасибо! Я как-то об этом даже не подумал